# Mylyn Context Automatically Attached

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla, mylyn

I want to attach context in a mylyn/bugzilla/eclipse enviroment automatically. Is it posible in any way?

I know I can do it everytime I need it by demand (right click in the task, attach context) but I want it with every commit in the task.

The idea is that every developer can download the context of every task whenever they want.

Any ideas?

Thanks.